# How can I prevent accidentally making bash quit, due to holding ctrl-d too long?

Tags: bash

I know how to disable ctrl-D by `set -o ignoreeof`, which applies when logged in over ssh as well.. But I only want to disable it when it is about to quit a local shell. How can I then?

In interactive bash shell, ctrl-d is used to delete characters in front, and to indicate the end of stdin input, and also makes bash quit.

Sometimes when I delete characters in front by ctrl-d, I hold the keys too long, and accidentally make bash quit. How can I prevent accidentally making bash quit?

Comment: "The linked duplicate post disables ctrl-D as eof unanimously"—that's very strange, `set -o ignoreeof` is not supposed to affect stdin input or character deletion.

Comment: @undercat: you are correct. Sorry. I changed to how to not allow it to quit ssh remote shell.

Comment: The question has now been edited into its own answer. _I know that `ignoreeof`is the way to do this.  How do I do this?_

Comment: @JdeBP As I understand it, the question is in the sentences which follow what you quote.  The OP wants to disable ctrl-D for the local shell while keeping it enabled for ssh.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete all characters on the line, try `Ctrl-K` instead.